# How make two-way of binding between grandchild and parent in angular2?

Tags: data-binding, angular, angular2-template, angular2-components, angular2-inputs

I need to do two way of binding between parent and grandchild. Thus, I try to do two-way of binding between child and other two.

Some think like that

GrandChild <==> Child <==> Parent

But it does not work as I expect.

This is my grandchild:

```
<svg [class.small-size]="!isFullScreen" [class.full-screen]="isFullScreen">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</svg>
...

export class FullScreenableSvgComponent {

  @Input() isFullScreen: Boolean;
  @Output() isFullScreenChange: EventEmitter<Boolean>;

  constructor() {
    this.isFullScreen = this.isFullScreen || false;
    this.isFullScreenChange = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
  }
  ...
}
```

This is my child:

```
<fullscreenable-svg (window:resize)="onResize()" [(isFullScreen)]="isFullScreen">
    ...
</fullscreenable-svg>

export class VisualizationComponent implements OnChanges, OnInit {

  @Input() isFullScreen: Boolean;
  @Output() isFullScreenChange: EventEmitter<Boolean>;

  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

    this.isFullScreenChange = new EventEmitter<Boolean>();
  }
  ...
}
```

This is my parent:

```
<visualization [(isFullScreen)]="isFullScreen" [nodes]="[]" [links]="[]">         
</visualization>
<div [hidden]="isFullScreen" style="position:absolute;">
    i am working
</div>
```

Comment: is there any error ?

Comment: No, but it is not working as expected.